# Tag wiki edit bug?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, editing, tag-wiki

I thought I had enough reputation to do all but the most powerful non-Moderator functions. However, my edits to tag wikis are going into the suggested edit queue (and I'm receiving a message to that effect).

The thing is, I have the approve tag wiki edits privilege. I can see that there are two pending edits (from my latest changes) but when I go to view the queue there's nothing there. I also get +2 reputation points when my changes are approved.

Is this a bug or am I misunderstanding a privilege?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [5k privilege mark](https://android.stackexchange.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) is kind of a weird privilege, because you can vote on tag wiki edits made by *others*, but yours still need approval, which seems rather bizarre. The reason the pending edits don't appear is because you cannot approve your own.

AFAIK, you have to hit [20k "Trusted User"](https://android.stackexchange.com/privileges/trusted-user) status in order to edit tag wikis without approval:

> ## What are trusted users?
>
> Trusted users are allowed to perform trusted actions, including:
>
> - Voting to delete answers with score of -1 or lower
> - Voting to undelete answers except those deleted by a moderator
> - Voting to delete questions immediately after they are closed (even if they are new)
> - **Editing all tag wikis on the site**

So from my understanding this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). [An answer from waffles (e.g. Sam Saffron) on Meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/108285/150283) appears to confirm this.

Comment: Makes sense, I guess. Go ahead and put [meta-tag:status-bydesign] on this question.

Comment: Pretty much all of the tag privileges require a weirdly high amount of rep.  Makes it hard for a lot of things regarding tags to be done by anyone except moderators.